# Derivative of $g(t) := f(tx + (1 − t)y)-tf(x)-(1-t)f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I want to calculate derivative of this function.
answer: 
$$g'(t)=<∇f((tx + (1 − t)y),x-y>-f(x)+f(y)\\ 
g''(t)=<∇^2f((tx + (1 − t)y)(x-y),x-y>$$
\
I tried but I couldn't.Can you help me please?\

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to math SE. First, have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions. Second, what have you tried?

Comment: @cebi. The function $g$ depends on $t,x,y$ thus it is not $g(t)$ but it is $g(t,x,y)$. What do you mean in writting $g'$ ? The derivative with respect to what variable ? Or are $x$ and $y$ constants parameters while $t$ is the unique variable?. Please clarify the wording of your question.

Comment: @JJacquelin I find in the book this question and answer.I understand this:I thing g depend on t.But in the case,f((tx+(1−t)y)  what depend on?   \\ g'(t) is derivative on t

Comment: Better clarify in the question itself, not in comment. You should use partial derivative symbol instead of prime which is an ambiguous notation in case of function with several variables. If the answer is in the book why asking here ? Explain what you understand in the book and where exactly you don't understand.

Comment: I didn't understand how the answer was found.I didnt understand f((tx+(1−t)y)'s derivative